# Como saber se é um fragment que está na tela, em teste de interface?

Tags: android, testes, testes-funcionais

Gostaria de saber, em testes automazidos de interface, como saber se um fragment está ou não na tela.

Caso seja um fragment, exemplo, ratingfragment, irei "performar" um "click".
Caso seja outro, farei outra ação.

Obrigado!

Código abaixo:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class CommunityUiTest {

    String emailSearch = "test@gmail.com";
    String emailLogin = "test22@ur.com";
    String pass = "2016";
    String pass2 = "2015";

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @After
    public void setUp(){
        Logout();
    }  
  @Test
    public void shouldOfferRide(){
        SystemClock.sleep(1500);
        Login();
        onView(withId(R.id.searchButton)).perform(typeText(emailSearch));
        onView(withId(R.id.searchButton)).perform(pressImeActionButton());
        onView(withId(R.id.community_user_ask_button)).perform(click());
        SystemClock.sleep(1500);
        onView(withId(R.id.button1)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.send_request)).perform(click());
        SystemClock.sleep(1500);
        ((MainActivity)mActivityRule.getActivity()).navItemClick(4);
        SystemClock.sleep(3500);
        LoginMyrides();
        onView(withId(R.id.my_rides_tab_bar)).perform(click());
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);

        //I have to know is ratingfragment before perform click below
        //Preciso saber se é o ratingfragment para executar ou não o perform(click) abaixo

        onView(withId(R.id.rating_bar)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.deny_btn)).perform(click());
    }

        public void Login(){
        onView(withId(R.id.edt_new_login_email)).perform(typeText(emailLogin));
        onView(withText(R.string.next_button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.edt_new_password)).perform(typeText(senha));
        onView(withText(R.string.login_new_pass)).perform(click());
    }

    public void Logout(){
        new SessionManager(mActivityRule.getActivity()).logoutUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muito ler vi que a resposta correta é que o espresso é desenvolvido para testes em cenario isolados, ou seja, deve ser montado um teste para quando o fragment estiver visivel.